# HQL and Like keyword

Tags: jsf, hql, sql-like

`nameFilter` is a string

`mo.name` is a string too

```
getEntityManager()
                .createQuery(
                        "select mo from MyObject mo JOIN mo.someOtherObject.product p where p=:product and mo.someEnum=:someEnum and mo.name like :name orderBy :sortField :sortOrder")
                .setParameter("name", "%"+nameFilter+"%")
                .setParameter("someEnum", SomeEnum.BlueOne)
                .setParameter("product", product)
                .setParameter("sortField", sortField)
                .setParameter("sortOrder", sortOrder).setFirstResult(first)
                .setMaxResults(pageSize).getResultList();
```

For above code i am getting the error unexpected token orderby.

What should i do?

I search for using like in hql but found too little thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `orderBy` keyword in HQL. You should write `order by` (two words).

Answer (score 1):

put a space in your order by in the hql statement.